# Problem in PHP/MYSQL crypt salt/hashing password

Tags: php, mysql

```
$salt = "\$5\$rounds=5000\$" . "bajojepicak" . $username . "\$";
        
$hash = crpyt($password, $salt);
    
$insertuserquery = "INSERT INTO players (username, hash, salt, email) VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $hash . "', '" . $salt . "', '" . $email . "');"; 
    
mysqli_query($con, $insertuserquery) or die("6: Insert player query failed");

echo "0";
```

I am learning and trying to SALT / HASH my password and i get an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function crpyt() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlconnect\register.php:58 Stack trace: #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sqlconnect\register.php on line 58

Is there someone who can help me figure out what is wrong or what is happening? If you need more code, i'll provide.

Comment: Don't do it this way. Use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: What is your version of php? I guess you should just enable `extension=php_mcrypt.dll` in your `php.ini`

Comment: check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash